# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not checking in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, google-chrome-extension

As you know, when send $.ajax(..) request to another domain (cross-domain), most browser throw exception like:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysite.com/test.php. Origin
 http://127.0.0.1:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am creating chrome extension and it should send a request to my website. First , i expected to see above message,too. But i confused when i see it worked fine.

First, It’s seem good, it’s working and i have what i want. But it can be horrible. Every one can use such way (only a simple script) to attack my site and grab its data.

Of course, grabbing could be happen in other ways, too.
I am new in api programing and chrome extension. Do anyone may show me the way?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyTestExtension",
  "description": "this extension is for test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs" ,
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","content_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]  
}
```

content_script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').mouseup(function() {
        var selectedText = getSelectedText();
        if(selectedText > ''){
            my_syncTest(selectedText)      // here : selected test send to my site
        }
    });

    function getSelectedText() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if(selection.trim() > ''){
                return selection;
            }
        } else if (document.selection) {
            var selection = document.selection.createRange().text;
            if(selection.trim() > ''){
                return selection;
            }
        }
        return '';
    } });


function my_syncTest(word){
var qs = 'word='+word+'&header=555&simwords=1'; 
$.ajax(
  {
   type: "POST", 
   url: 'http://mysite.com/test.php',
   dataType: 'json', 
   data : qs, 

  success:function(res){
    console.log(res.success +" - "+ res.idWord + " - " + res.header +" - " + res.meaning);
  }});
}
```

Comment: Cross-origin security is not about stopping malicious software sending requests to your website - it's designed to stop one webpage pretending to be the _user_ accessing another webpage.

Answer (score 8):

XMLHttpRequests from your extension work because you defined these permissions in the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
]
```

When a user installs your extension, he is informed that this extension can access his data on all sites. I prefer only including the exact site you need instead of wildcards.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

This mechanism is to protect the user, not to protect your site. If you don't want everybody to use your API, use API-keys, or look into oAuth:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

If you want to learn more about cross origin requests:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: hi swonkie
i changed "*://*/*" to otherurl like "http://google.com/". but I can access to my site, yet!!

Comment: Did you use the full URL including http:// or https:// ?
When you go to the extensions page chrome://extensions/ you can click Permissions under your extension to see what it actually uses.

Comment: yes i used full url: '"permissions": ["htt p://google.com/*" , "tabs" ]' .
and the Permissions in chrome://extensions/ is : " 1:Access your data on all websites.  2: Access your tabs and browsing activity " .
and i used "load nnpacked extension... ".

Comment: OK now I'm confused. If it says "access your data on all websites" it means you have used the wildcards *://*/* and XMLHttpRequests should work.
In your first comment, did you mean "you can still access your site" or "you still can NOT access your site"? Also reload your extension after editing.